# ImportError: Cannot import 'views' from '__main__'

Tags: python, django

This is the url.py file in the polls app on my website(project) file:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),   
]
```

```
File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from '__main__' (/storage/emulated/0/website/polls/urls.py)
```

Now the main urls.py file in the website file

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import include, path

    urlpatterns = [
        path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),

        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
```

Traceback code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>    
start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
File 

    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

[Program finished]
```

I have tried the polls urls.py like this
  from polls import views

but it gets a Module Error so what's the issue with the code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate your views and urls create a new module (file) urls.py in your app, in your case it is weather folder, and add these code there, and remove it from views.py, you can read here about it to understand it better.

`Path :

> the_weather/weather/urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),  #the path for our index view
]
```